# OpenSource Wiki hosting

Tags: hosting, format, markdown, gollum-wiki, codaset

I have several .md files (in markdown format) initially on github, but I would like to put it up as a wiki with a custom link. I use the [Gollum gem](https://github.com/github/gollum) and like it alot, however it is only built on top of github or use in local server to edit the files offline.

Are there any opensource wiki that reads markdown format that I can create and point the wiki to my hosted domain?

Appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some likely candidates:

- [w2wiki](http://code.google.com/p/w2wiki/) - PHP based, "A web-based, wiki-like notepad that you host yourself"
- [Markdoc](http://markdoc.org/) - Python based
- [Gitit](http://gitit.net/) - "a wiki backed by a git, darcs, or mercurial filestore". Uses Pandoc for markup so supports several formats.
- [ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/) - A WIKI "compiler" based around a revision control backend
- [nikiwiki](https://github.com/synack/nikiwiki) - Python based
- [Beautiful docs](http://beautifuldocs.com/) - "a documentation viewer based on markdown files", uses Node.js
- [Commonplace](http://helloform.com/projects/commonplace/) - Ruby-based but written for Mac desktop (should work elsewhere thougH). Not sure this is really classed as a WIKI but it does display MD formatted files